# Before Save Failing to Reference Has Many Association in Factory Bot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I an invoice model with many invoice line items. On the invoice model, there is a before save callback that totals the invoice line items and sets the total field on the invoice:

```
# invoice.rb model
before_save :set_total
#...
private 

    def set_total
        self.total = invoice_line_items.sum("quantity * price")
    end
```

Here is the invoice factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :invoice do
    due_date {30.days.from_now}
    notes {"Some notes here, chap."}
    paid {false}
    paid_date {nil}

    factory :invoice_with_line_items do

      invoice_line_items { build_list :invoice_line_item, 2 }

    end

    service_order
  end
end
```

And some test code:

```
RSpec.describe Invoice, type: :model do
  let(:invoice) {
    create(:invoice_with_line_items)
  }
  describe "#total" do
    it "calculates total of all line items" do

      binding.pry
      expect(invoice.total).to eq (50.99*4).to_d
    end
  end
```

However, in my rspec tests that use factory bot, the total is always set to 0 almost as if the callback is not firing at all or is firing before the associations are created.

How can I get the before save callback to work so that it sees the association?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem didn't lie in factory bot, but rather with my logic in the before save callback. SUM depends on the database, so new records aren't seen. I updated the code to the following and it works fine:

```
    # invoice.rb model before_save callback
    def set_total
        ili_total = 0
        invoice_line_items.each do |ili|
           ili_total += ili.quantity * ili.price 
        end
        self.total = ili_total 
    end
```